# Save file to device with memorystream

Tags: file, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, memorystream

I was wondering if it is possible with xamarin.forms to download any type of file to the device.. de files are stored on Azure, i get a Memorystream of the file, its very important for my app. my question excists of 2 parts actually, 
how to download de file to the device of the user?, 
and how to show the file of Any type in a default application of the type ( like pdf reader)

this is what i tried

> MemoryStream memoryStream = AzureDownloader.DownloadFromAzureBlobStorage(null, doc.azure_container, doc.file_path, ref filen, true);

```
  string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
  string localFilename = doc.filename;
  string localPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
  File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, memoryStream.ToArray()); // this is a try to save to local storage
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> how to download the file to the device of the user?

Use [PCLStorage](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/pclstorage) as its cross-platform and would work for iOS and Android:

```
public async Task CreateRealFileAsync()
{
    // get hold of the file system
    IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;

    // create a folder, if one does not exist already
    IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MySubFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    // create a file, overwriting any existing file
    IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("MyFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    // populate the file with some text
    await file.WriteAllTextAsync("Sample Text...");
}
```

> how to show the file of Any type in a default application of the type
>   ( like pdf reader)

this is too broad and could have several solutions depending on what exactly you want to achieve.

Hope this helps

Comment: It works for pdf files. As long as path and file name are correct. For example, you can use _"fileName.pdf"_

Comment: but does it work in a shared project? and does it also work for excel files?

Comment: yes, it works in shared project that's why its called "PCL". And as long as file formats are concerned, it loads text or bytes data which you can use to process as you want

Comment: wait you have shared project and you have PCL so its possible for both? i am new to xamarin.forms. i am using the shared project.. so, i let you know if this code worked tomorrow. thanks for you answer

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I meant PCL not sure about shared project. You can try it in shared project and find out