# How to download a memory stream as file to your device in Xamarin.forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, save, memorystream

I get a memorystream back from the server where my files are stored but how can I download these files to the device of the user and after that open the file?

I only get the memorystream back, and I need to show the user the file in a default viewer of the device. I am not working with an open source server so it needs to be with the memorystream.

Comment: What about reading from the stream?

Comment: You have asked this before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410562/save-file-to-device-with-memorystream There was an answer. But you did not even react. If you are known as not reacting nobody will help you further.

Comment: In your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410562/save-file-to-device-with-memorystream), Umair M's could solve your problem.